# Is there a general algorithm to decide whether an integer value is attainable by a quadratic form?

Tags: algorithms, diophantine-equations, computational-complexity, quadratic-forms

I'm not sure if I phrased the question correctly, but let's say that due to [a result called 15 theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_and_290_theorems) that "if a positive definite quadratic form with integer matrix represents all positive integers up to $15$, the it represents all positive integers". As I'm new to the theory of quadratic forms (I only read, partially, the first lecture of "THE SENSUAL (quadratic) FORM" by Conway and Fung), I'm interested by the question of checking whether an integer value is retrieved as a result of a quadratic form.

More formally, for any fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, given $A \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ positive definite and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, is there a general algorithm to find (or decide whether there exists) $x \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times 1}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $x^T A x = k$?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but from a "numerical" point of view, I think one can find the roots of the multivariate polynomial $E(x) = x^T A x - k$, and check for each root whether it is an integer. This may be able to solve using some traditional multivariate polynomial root finding algorithms (which I don't know, and I'm not sure if it works). Is there any algorithm that specifically answer this problem (numerically, algebraically, or combinatorially)?

At first, it looks as if it is an NP problem, since given $x \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times 1}(\mathbb{R})$ (in particular, I'd rather say $\mathcal{M}_{n \times 1}(\mathbb{Q})$ instead), one can verify the equation $x^T A x = k$ easily. However, due to [something like this (The Uncracked Problem with 33 - Numberphile)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wymmCdLdPvM), I'm afraid that $x$ might be very large, and hence, might contain information bigger than polynomial on $n$.

**Edit**: To ask for a solution in $\mathbb{R}^n$, this looks like I'm asking the wrong question. Since it is positive definite, I can descend ($\mathbb{R}^n$-wise) the "well" to find the minimum real $m > 0$ representable by the form, then any integer $k \geq m$ is representable by the form at some point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ due to continuity and unboundedness of the form. So maybe the interesting question is to find solutions in $\mathbb{Q}^n$ or $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Note that I also found this [Wikipedia article on Hilbert's 11th problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_eleventh_problem), which I haven't yet understood it completely. Further explanations are appreciated.

**Edit 2.** No. The original "descend the well" algorithm only works on integral binary quadratic forms, but in this case the interesting question lies on a more general setting of multivariate (more than 2 variables) quadratic forms. But I guess there should be something that works the same, i.e., some algorithm that gives the minimum real value represented by a quadratic form. Hmm... I don't know.

**Edit 3.** As suggested by Gerry Myerson, I'm editing this to explicitly state the question as follows:

**Problem.** For $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ fixed, given symmetric positive definite $A \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{Z})$, and given $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Is there a general algorithm to find $x \in K^n$ such that $x^T A x = k$?

*Question 0.* For $K = \mathbb{R}$ (answered by Gerry Myerson in the comments)

*Question 1.* For $K = \mathbb{Q}$.

*Question 2.* For $K = \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If a multivariate quadratic form has a minimum real value, this can only happen at a point where all the partial derivatives are zero, which gives you a system of linear equations to solve.

Comment: Also, it appears that sometimes you are allowing variables with real components, when the action concerns variables with integer components. You might want to go over your question, and edit for consistency.

Comment: $x^\top A x\ge c \|x\|^2$ where $c$ is the least eigenvalue of $A$, so $c^{-1}$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$, so that $c^{-1}\le \sup_{ij}|A^{-1}_{ij}|$.

Comment: OK, so, you are asking (among other things) for a general algorithm to find a representation of a given integer by a given positive definite quadratic form with integer coefficients, evaluated at a point with integer components. Whole books have been written about this problem, even about special cases of this problem, e.g., David Cox' book, Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$. For any given integer, and any given quadratic form, it is of course a finite calculation, but to ask the question in full generality is to ask for way too much.

Comment: 1. Please don't use "Edit".  Instead, revise your question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  No need to keep track of what has changed or the path by which you got to the ultimate question.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.  2. Please ask only one question per post.  If you have multiple questions, you can ask them separately.